# Html5 video preload is blocking async scripts

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a page with, to simplify:

```
<script async src="..."></script>
[...]
<video preload="auto" ...>
```

That script loads some other scripts asynchronously (so removing the "async" doesn't solve the issue) to load some ads.

The problem is that every network connection is kept pending until the video has finished downloading, and it may take too much time it the video is long and the user has a slow connection.

How can we solve the issue? I thought about deferring the video preloading via javascript after window.onload... Is there any better way?

Also, would upgrading to HTTP2 fix it?

Comment: do you need the video to be there quickly? I would maybe have a script that's triggered on page load to populate the source of the video only when the desired scripts have loaded

Answer (score 1):

Is it guaranteed that users will want to watch the video? If not, then I would advise setting preload to either "none" or "metadata" only. It's not a good idea to force users to download an entire video that they may not even watch.